# Neighborhood and closures

Tags: general-topology

For every $\epsilon>0$, neighborhood $N(x;\epsilon)\cap A \neq\emptyset$
implies

For every open set $U$, if $x\in U$ then $U\cap A \neq \emptyset$ implies

$x\in \text{closure of }A$

I am confused how should I approach to solve this question.

Comment: which definition are you taking for closure?

Comment: Closure of A = A union Accumulation point of A

Answer (score 0):

Let $B=\{x\ |\ \forall U\ {\rm neighborhood\ of}\ x:U\cap A\neq\emptyset\}$ be the set of all points with your property.

Let $A'$ be the set of accumulation points.

We will prove $B\smallsetminus A\subset A'$. Then $B\subset A\cup A'$.

For, if $x\in B\smallsetminus A$ then for each neighborhood $U$ of $x$ it happens that $U\cap A\neq\emptyset$, but, since $x\notin A$, then $U\cap (A\smallsetminus\{x\})\neq\emptyset$ too, that is, $x\in A'$.

Comment: I am not sure actually how to get from $x\in B \setminus A$ to $U\cap A\neq \emptyset$. Could you please explain more to me about that? Thanks in advance

Comment: if $x\notin A$ then $A=A\smallsetminus\{x\}$ and  $U\cap (A\smallsetminus\{x\})=U\cap A\neq\emptyset$

Answer (score 0):

If $N(x,\epsilon)\cap A$ is non-empty for every $\epsilon >0$ and $U$ is any open set containing $x$ then $N(x,\epsilon) \subset U$ for  some $\epsilon>0$ so $U \cap A$ is also non-empty.

If $U \cap A$ is non-empty for every open set $U$ conatining $x$ then $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$: if this is not true then there exisst $\epsilon >0$ such that  $N(x,\epsilon)$ contains only finite number of points of $A$ other than $x$. If these points are $x_1,x_2,..,x_N$ take $\epsilon'$ to be the minimum of $\epsilon$ and the numbers $d(x,x_i), 1 \leq i \leq N$. Then check that $N(x,\epsilon) \cap A$is empty, leading to a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Either $x \in A$ or $x \not \in A$.

If $x \in A$ then all three statements are true.

If $x \not \in A$ then the first statement is true if and only if every neighborhood contains a point or points of $A$ which can not be $x$ as $x \not \in A$.  That is the very definition of accumulation point.

If $x\not \in A$ he third statement is true if and only if $x \in \{$accumulation points of $A\} \cup A$ but not in $A$ so is an accumulation point.

So both statements one and three claim the exact same thing: either $x$ is in $A$ or $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$.

As every neigbhorhood of $x$ is an open set containing $x$ then statement two, a statement about every open set containing $x$, implies statement one, the exact same statement but restricted to neighborhoods, a specific *type* of open sets.

So we have $1 \iff 3$ and $2 \implies 1$.

Now the definition of open set, $U$, is that for every point $x$ in $U$, there is an $N(x,\epsilon) \subset U$.

If we assume 1) then for every open set $U$ so that $x\in U$ then there is a neighborhood $N(x,\epsilon)$ so that $N(x,\epsilon) \subset U$.  Because we are assuming $1$ then $N(x\epsilon)\cap A$ isn't empty.  But $N(x,\epsilon) \subset U$ so $U\cap A \supset N(x\epsilon)\cap A$ and $U\cap A$ isn't empty so 2) is true.

So $1\iff 3$ and $2\implies 1$ and $1 \implies 2$.

So all three are equivalent.